# How to print html tag in php variable?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a space between line yet it does not work. It suppose to go to the next line. Instead of printing space it actually prints the html tag 
. Any clue how to fix this problem?

SettingController.php

```
$content = "Someone purchase your picture".<br><br>;

foreach ($request->input('pic') as $key => $value) {
    $content .= "$key : $value".<br>;
    }
```

Comment: Use this `$content = "Someone purchase your picture<br><br>"; $content .= $key. ":" .$value."<br>";`

Answer (score 2):

Search for how html and php can be integrated you will find lots of answers and tutorials

For your code you need to add `""` for html tags

```
$content = "Someone purchase your picture"."<br><br>";

foreach ($request->input('pic') as $key => $value) {
    $content .= "$key : $value"."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: It actually print out the <br> instead of showing a real spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I actually email the result instead printing them on the web browser:

```
 public function SendPicture(Request $request)
 {

    $title = "Picture Purchase";
    //$picture = $request->input('pic');


    $content = "Someone purchase your picture"."<br><br>";

    foreach ($request->input('pic') as $key => $value) {

        $content .= "$value".".jpg"."<br>";

        }


    Mail::send('soulfy.email.purchase', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) //use ($attach)
    {

        $message->from('davy.yg1@gmail.com', 'Admin');

        $message->to(['davy_yg@yahoo.com', 'stokfoto@soulfy.com']);

        //Attach file
        //$message->attach($attach);

        //Add a subject
        $message->subject("Picture Purchase");

    });

    return redirect('home/setting');

}
```

email/purchase.blade.php

```
 {{$title}}

  <br><br>

  {{$content}}
```

Comment: Depending on the email service you are using, its possible you don't have to use <br> tag and just hit the enter button in the template to start on the next line.

Comment: What template service are you using?

Comment: This is laravel